# To upload the image to the firestore when I click the upload button by using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am creating a web site that has the image upload to it, I want to upload the image only when I click the upload button.
here is the code that im using right now.

```
fileBtn.addEventListener('change', function(e){
for(let i =0; i<e.target.files.length; i++){
let imageFile = e.target.files[i];
let storageRef = firebase.storage().ref("Images" + imageFile.name);
let storageRef = firebase.storage().ref("Images/ProPic" + imageFile.name);
let task = storageRef.put(imageFile);      
}
})
```

Comment: What is the difficulty you are facing then ?

Comment: Hi @zaheerabbas, welcome to Stackoverflow. I understand that you are trying to upload image files to Firebase when a user clicks on an "upload" button. I can notice you added an event listener to fire the "upload" button, and you declared some references `storageRef` (not sure why there are two) to your database. What is the issue you are encountering? Any errors? Please provide the community with as much information as possible to be able to help you.

Comment: Try checking out this [guide about Setting up a file upload feature](https://medium.com/@mheavers/setting-up-a-basic-file-upload-feature-for-your-static-website-with-just-javascript-using-firebase-32464580d8bb) and let me know if it helps you.